# Python shove module not working after py2app build on mac

Tags: python, persistence

I am using the [shove](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/shove/) module for object persistence. It works fine but when I attempt to build the app using py2app, it ceases to work. The following code works normally except after freezing using py2app:

```
import os
from shove import Shove

if __name__ == '__main__':
    home=os.path.expanduser("~") 
    path = os.path.join(home, 'testdb')
    uri = 'file://{0}'.format(path)
    print path
    print uri

    db = Shove(uri)
    print db.keys()

    db['1'] = 'dog'
    db['2'] = 'cat'
    db.sync()
    db.close()
```

The setup.py file contains the following:

```
from setuptools import setup

OPTIONS = dict(
argv_emulation = True,
includes=['future_builtins','concurrent.futures']
)

DATA_FILES = []


setup(
    app='highlightdb.py',
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

The traceback I am getting is:

```
highlightdb[68150]:     db = Shove(uri)
highlightdb[68150]:   File "shove/core.pyc", line 23, in __init__
highlightdb[68150]:   File "shove/_imports.pyc", line 46, in store_backend
highlightdb[68150]: KeyError: 'file'
```

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem is that shove functionality is largely implemented using plugins, which are loaded using *pkg_resources.iter_entry_points*. Unfortunately py2app doesn't support iter_entry_points. Nevertheless I found [this](https://github.com/glue-viz/glue/blob/master/glue/_plugin_helpers.py), which may be a possible workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restarted Python after installing Shove?

The same KeyError: 'file' happens if you don't restart:  you can import the library, but Shove can't load any modules